# Issues with Scatter Gather in Mule 4.2.2

Tags: mule

Is there any known issue with scatter gather scope in Mule Runtime 4.2.2(On-prem). I could see few of my request is not moving after the scatter gather component with no error or exceptions. I do invoking the soap service , rest service and file consuming under the scatter gather component. Its not happening for all the request but for few request. It is causing timeout for that request.I do have before and after logger . Its does not showing any before activities as well. On the same time, another request process it successfully.

I am just using basic config of scatter-gather component.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible example of the problem along with associated timings for successful and timeout cases. Did you check the 4.2.2 release notes for any clues-I note there are a number of issues with Scatter Gather identified in the 4.3.0 release notes here https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-runtime/mule-4.3.0-release-notes

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 6 fixed issues with scatter-gather mentioned in the Mule 4.3.0 release notes. This means that the issues were reported against previous versions. You can check those issues by searching the id number (MULE-NNNNN) in Mule JIRA: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira to see if any has affected version 4.2.2.

You have also to consider the possibility that the issue is related to something else, like threading.

It would be a good idea to test with Mule 4.3.0 to see if you notice any improvements.

Comment: I monitor in dynatrace I got this exceptions 
org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.exception.InvalidPropertyNameException
Message
Invalid property name: `headers` on class `org.mule.extension.ws.api.SoapAttributes`. Validate that the correct setters is present I have dataweave and set header to soap consume inside scatter gather component.

Comment: You should provide more details of the configurations, and enable HTTP Wire Logging. It is possible that the SOAP service is not answering correctly.